# Raspbian + XBMC YouTube will not play

Tags: raspbian, video, kodi

XBMC will not play some YouTube HD videos properly. As far as I can tell it works for SD videos. I already tried adding

```
start_x=1
```

to the */boot/config.txt* file, as this seems to have helped some people. I also tried setting the max. resolution from 1080p to "Ask" as suggested here[1].

I am running the latest XBMC version from[2] on Raspbian.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

[1] [Youtube video playback fails on XBMC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10345/youtube-video-playback-fails-on-xbmc)

[2] http://michael.gorven.za.net/raspberrypi/xbmc

Comment: For anyone who might experience a similar problem: Increasing the video memory might help. I set it to 128 MB according to [1]. Fixed the problem.

[1] https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/673/what-is-the-optimum-split-of-main-versus-gpu-memory

Comment: If you solved your problem please create a self-answer and then, when possible, flag it as answer. That would be great, as it shows that the site is solving problems, and thus increases our chance of moving on from the Beta stage. Thanks!

Comment: Aye, didn't have enough reputation at the time.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. I saw the log file and its related to Youtube addon. We can send a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who might experience a similar problem: Increasing the video memory might help. I set it to 128 MB according to [1]. Fixed the problem.

[1] [What is the optimum split of main versus GPU memory?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/673/what-is-the-optimum-split-of-main-versus-gpu-memory)

Comment: Hey Phil, if you've answered your own question you can set your answer as the "accepted answer"